# How do I render a svg as a mesh in three js

Tags: three.js

Im trying to render a SVG file as a mesh using SVGLoader in my three js application, but its not working

I followed the documentation to the SVGLoader step by step but still nothing

here is the documentation : https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=svg#examples/en/loaders/SVGLoader

and here is my code that i've tried :

```
    const loader = new SVGLoader();
    const group = new Group();
    loader.load(
      "../public/assets/svg/logo.svg",
      function (data) {
        const paths = data.paths;

        for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
          const path = paths[i];

          const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: path.color,
            side: DoubleSide,
            depthWrite: false,
          });

          const shapes = SVGLoader.createShapes(path);

          for (let j = 0; j < shapes.length; j++) {
            const shape = shapes[j];
            const geometry = new ShapeGeometry(shape);
            const mesh = new Mesh(geometry, material);
            group.add(mesh);
          }
        }
      },
      function (xhr) {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log("An error happened", error);
      }
    );

    scene.add(group);
```

Im not getting any error messages when I run my code.

Comment: Consider to demonstrate what you are doing with a live example.

Comment: @Mugen87 yes i have github repo here is the link :
https://github.com/Nacir1i/three-vanilla-temp/blob/main/three/World.js

Comment: @Mugen87 Hello, can you please help me with this x)

Comment: The link you have shared is no live example. I've expected something like https://jsfiddle.net/92fuxmj1/